# Formula to unfold circle to straight line -

Tags: image-processing, formula, polar-coordinates

I am looking for a simple conversion/transformation formula, such that:
In a square region sized d*d, containing a circle with diameter d (tangent to the 4 sides of the square),

1. all points on the circle are equidistantly transformed/unfolded/remapped into a straight line along the top or bottom edge of the square,
2. the center point of the circle is transformed/stretched all along the opposite edge of the square,
3. all points inside the circle are transformed the same way, and the resulting left and right sides can be tiled seamlessly, and
4. all points outside the circle are out of range of the square after the transformation, and are not visible.
   In this before and after example, d=1:

> ```
>      Before              After
>      ------              -----
>       0 , 0       -->     0 , 1  (the only infinitely stretched point)
>       0 , -1      -->     0 , -1 (the only unchanged point)
>       0 , 1       -->    -1 , -1 and 1 , -1
>       1 , 0       -->   1/2 , -1
>      -1 , 0       -->  -1/2 , -1
>  √(1/2) , √(1/2)  -->   3/4 , -1
>  √(1/2) , -√(1/2) -->   1/4 , -1
> -√(1/2) , √(1/2)  -->  -3/4 , -1
> -√(1/2) , -√(1/2) -->  -1/4 , -1
>       1 , 1       -->   out of range
>       1 , -1      -->   out of range
>      -1 , 1       -->   out of range
>      -1 , -1      -->   out of range
> ```

This is related to polar/Cartesian (r,theta) to (x,y) conversion and/or arctan. The formula would be usable on graphing calculators like desmos.

For visual thinkers, here is a before & after graph of the transformation. Note that the circle before is along the bottom after, and that the transformed dots can be tiled horizontally.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could choose 3-4 points and mark them on both the left and right images so humans can understand what you mean... ;-)

Comment: did exactly that, with the light-blue coordinates in the images.

Comment: Sorry, it’s as clear as mud to me I can’t tell which dots in the output image correspond to which on the input image at all. It would help if you could choose 2 dots in each of two quadrants of the input image and mark each of the 4 in a distinct colour in both input and output images.

Comment: OK, https://i.imgur.com/jhtoxrV.png
it is very much the same effect as Photoshop's "polar to rectangular" Polar Coordinates filter. basically, scanning a round area clockwise 360 degrees, then rearranging those radial scans to be parallel to each other, in a square as wide and tall as the original circle.

Comment: --> how would you take a radar, and turn it square? that is the question, in a nutshell. how would you take a classic round plot of radial lines, and turn all the lines vertical and parallel to each other? need that formula :-)

Comment: I got the desired effect, through trial and error. the code is a work in a progress, but it works. thanks Mark for your help. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/davhovnkru

Comment: If you were doing this in 3D, I'd just convert lat/long into x/y and plot.